# UIImageViews inside UITableViewCell don't become selected

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I am creating the table with the custom UITableViewCells represented on this image:

[image]

In the left part of the cell there are a gray UIImageView, three labels and an UIImageView with a line.  Cells can have different height, based on their content. If i insert one image as a background, this image will be stretched. So i have created two UIImageViews: top (from the top of the cell to the bottom of the first semicircle) and bottom (from the bottom of the last semicircle to the bottom of the cell) and the UIView with a pattern image background color. Pattern image in this view is repeated in order to fill UIView completely. I also calculate height of the cell in order to UIView join bottom UIImageView correctly.

My problem is: when the cell is selected my imageViews are not selected. Only middle UIView becomes selected. You can see this in the pictures below:
[image]

[image]

I want all imageViews(top, bottom ad gray) to become selected with the cell. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the method in your UITableViewCell subclass.

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    self.imageView.image = [UImage imageNamed:@"some_other_image.png"];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought about this, but in this way i will have to add 4 additional images to my project. This will increase the size of my app. Maybe there is any another way? I really don't understand, why not all of the cell's subviews become selected.

Comment: Did you add the imageViews to the contentView? Its basicly only the background color of the tableview cell that changes color on a standard tableview. The extra images shouldnt be that big of a deal with regards to the final size of the app.